# Как отправить значения true/false через чекбокс?

Tags: php, html

Написал чекбокс в форме:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox" value="true">
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает что **value:true** передаст строку. Как сделать так, если флажок помечен отправить **true**, а если не помечен **false**?

Comment: У `type="checkbox"` нет `value`, но есть свойство `checked`

Comment: Без `value` у меня вообще `on` отправлял

Comment: Создайте несколько инпутов, часть отметьте, отправьте и посмотрите, какие значения придут. На стороне клиента, в `input type="checkbox"` положить value не получится, оно будет проигнорировано.

Comment: Если чек-бокс отмечен то в `$_POST` есть его `value` или `"on"` если `value` нет. Если чек-бокс не отмечен, но его и в `$_POST` нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передать булево значение нельзя.
Когда передается форма на сервер( допустим метод POST), то если есть хоть один выбранный чекбокс, то передастся строка `$_POST['my_checkbox']=string("true")` в вашем случае **true** при этом передается как **string**, а если ничего не выбрано, то просто нет **$_POST['my_checkbox']**, т.е. `isset($_POST['my_checkbox'])результат false`

Если у вас в форме будет несколько чекбоксов
`<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox[]" value="true"> <input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox[]" value="false">`
то передаваться будет массив

Comment: Немного добавлю как можно преобразовывать типы https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var 
$boolean = filter_var($myString, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);

Answer (score 1):

`input[type="checkbox"]` игнорируется если не имеет состояние `checked === true`, а если имеет, то отправляет `on` если `value` пустое или значение самого `value` если там что-то указано.

Можно со стороны сервера перепроверять есть ли наличие `name` данного input'а, и там уже присваивать `true\false` в зависимости от наличия..
Но думаю это не правильно, т.к. его вообще может не быть.

По этому как вариант предлагаю при отправки формы пересобирать данные для отправки.
Данные записывать в [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData), там проверять наличие `input[type="checkbox"]` и тут же выдавать записывать его значение как `true\false` в зависимости от того, какое состояние `input.checkbox` на данный момент.

```js
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(form) { // при отправке формы
    form.preventDefault(); // отменяем отправку
    const data = new FormData(); // создаём объект FormData
    const inputs = form.target.querySelectorAll('[name]'); // Собираем все инпуты с атрибутом name
    if(inputs.length > 0) { // Если их больше нуля..
        inputs.forEach(function(input) { // Проходим по ним циклом
            var name = input.name; // получаем значение атрибута name
            var value = input.value; // получаем значение атрибута value
            
            if(input.type === 'checkbox') { // Если инпут == чекбоксу, то..
                value = input.checked; // в переменную value записываем его состояние checked (true || false)
            }
            
            data.append(name, value); // добавляем это в FormData
        })
    }
    console.info(data);
  // Вот тут отправляем данные на сервер
    return false;
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label>Укажите ваше имя</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Василий"/>
  <br>
  <label>Вы робот?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="is-robot" value="true"/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

---

P.s. в примере данные возвращаются в консоль, её откройте девтулом, в сниппете она криво отображает данные.